# Split String With Commas in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a dynamic query that will allow me to have multiple values in once Variable. To get this right I have been working on the following query:

```
DECLARE 
@Variables VARCHAR(MAX) = 'MOVE ON UP,WILD BREAK,PRETWIST',
@Result VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Result = (SELECT REPLACE(@Variables, ',', '') )
SELECT 
S = STUFF((
SELECT ',' +S
FROM(
        SELECT S= '''' + SUBSTRING(@Result, N, 1) + ''''
         FROM (SELECT TOP (LEN(@Result)) N= ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM master..spt_values ) N
    ) B1
FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')
```

My query gives the output as:

> 'M','O','V','E',' ','O','N',' ','U','P','W','I','L','D',' ','B','R','E','A','K','P','R','E','T','W','I','S','T'

Where as my desired output is:

> 'MOVE ON UP','WILD BREAK','PRETWIST'

Please could someone assist me and show me where I am going wrong?

Comment: What is ms sql version?

Comment: Hi Alex, it's SQL v17.9

Comment: Is this not as simple as replacing each comma with the desired 3 characters?

Comment: There is no SQL 17.9. The latest version is version 15.

Comment: 17.9 sounds like your version of management studio. Execute the query `SELECT @@VERSION` to see what version of SQL Server you are connecting too.

Comment: It likely is, @ChrisCatignani , but the version of SSMS has very little to do with the version of SQL Server. SSMS V18 supports SQL Server 2008-2019 (that's 7 different versions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a 2008+ compliant approach which does not require macro substitution nor dynamic SQL

**Example**

```
DECLARE @Variables VARCHAR(MAX) = 'MOVE ON UP,WILD BREAK,PRETWIST'

Select A.*
 From  YourTable A
 Where [SomeCol] in (
                    Select Value = B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')
                    From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace(@Variables,',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml)) as A 
                    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
                  )
```

**Or as a JOIN**

```
DECLARE @Variables VARCHAR(MAX) = 'MOVE ON UP,WILD BREAK,PRETWIST'

Select A.*
 From  YourTable A
 Join  (
        Select Value = B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')
        From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace(@Variables,',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml)) as A 
        Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
       ) B
 on A.StateCode=B.Value
```

Comment: Yes! Worked like a charm :) Thank you, John. I will go research further what exactly you have done ;)

Comment: @GrayMeiring The Select Value ... portion converts your string into XML and then we convert that into a table which can be used in a JOIN or IN ... Fun stuff !

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% clear on your intent, however ...

**Example**

```
DECLARE @Variables VARCHAR(MAX) = 'MOVE ON UP,WILD BREAK,PRETWIST'

Select ''''+replace(@Variables,',',''',''')+''''
```

**Returns**

```
'MOVE ON UP','WILD BREAK','PRETWIST'
```

Comment: Omg! Thank you! :) I literally have been over thinking this :/

Comment: @GrayMeiring Happens to all of us.  Happy to help

Comment: Hi John. Perhaps you can assist me further. My goal was to use the above with my `WHERE IN` clause, thus allowing multiple values to be declared at the start. But when my where clause now is `WHERE IN (Select ''''+replace(@Variables,',',''',''')+''''` the query returns no results?

Comment: @GrayMeiring SQ: Server does not support macro substitution.  Give me a moment ant I can update my answer

Comment: @GrayMeiring I added a second answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use STRING_SPLIT() function:

```
Select
Value
From STRING_SPLIT(@Variables, ',');
```

Which will return you rows with your words
https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

And then gather it as you wish with xml path or string_agg as you wish

Comment: Thank you, but for this I need to change my compatibility. The final use of this script I wanted to work on anyone's SQL.